# HTML flash like text replication

Tags: html, css

In the site - http://www.suneeta-rao.com/albums.htm, The text "Suneeta rao" is configured using flash. Is it possible to configure the same using HTML and CSS only. The effect i am talking about is the white  flash like thing moving across each letter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in html/css only.

What you want is the `:hover` pseudo-class in css and a radial background gradient.

See this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2vqggbxj/

I generated the background gradient css mess using this site (you'll probably want to tinker with it to get it just the way you want it):
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

HTML:

```
<span class="hoverable">Hello</span>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverable:hover
{
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

body
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```